# How to add colorbox in views gallery

Tags: views, javascript, media

> I follow these steps to achieve the gallery thumbnail in footer
>   https://www.drupal.org/node/1497058
>   and now my thumbnails shows like below
>   [image]
>
> but only thing left is when i
>   click thumbnail image its open the next page and show the big image
>   but i want when i click the thumbnail the big page open on colorbox
>   when i click on thumbnail its shown like below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install and enable [colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) module. And add place [colorbox library](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/archive/1.x.zip) in sites/all/library and rename folder to colorbox

1. Goto to admin/structure/views
2. Click edit on your views, here my view name is "Colorbox"

[image]

3. Click on your image field, eg., content:Image

[image]

4. select Formatter as **`colorbox`** and click "apply"

[image]

5. Save the view and clear the cache.

Hope it works

Comment: where  you find the above screen when i click o n views under structure there is no such field

Comment: You need to install and configure the colorbox module.

Comment: Answer updated. Kindly check it.

Comment: @vamsi: i followed your step, now when i click the thumbnail the big image open there but not in colobox there is no cross button and all

Comment: <a href="http://localhost/nic/sites/default/files/18.jpg" title="Photo" class="colorbox" data-colorbox-gallery="gallery-node-8-g0Y1aS1dNcE"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/nic/sites/default/files/18.jpg" alt="" title="" width="800" height="533"></a>

Comment: Above is the view source. Is anything missing in it?

Comment: i added the pic in questions

Comment: Go to admin/reports/status and check if you find any error like "colorbox library is missing"

Comment: no there is no such thing there

Comment: Then it should work. Clear your cache and try.

Comment: okay let me check

Comment: Is it working now.

Comment: yes perfectly working